# How to compile two different libraries in same Android.mk linking one of them to other

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, makefile

I have source code of 2 different libraries, FooMain and FooSecondary. FooSecondary is used by FooMain, so, makefile must compile First FooSecondary, then compile FooMain, and then link FooSecondary to FooMain.

My Android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

# Foo Secondary lib:

# Clear vars
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# Target Build
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm   
# Library Name          
LOCAL_MODULE := FooSecondary        
# Set All SRC_FILES Together            
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/FooSecondary/src/*.c)
SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)     
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(SRC_FILES)
# Enable Log support
LOCAL_LDLIBS = -llog    
# C   Flags - Max optimization              
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -mno-thumb
# C++ Flags - Max optimization          
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O3 -mno-thumb
# Compile as Shared Library     
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)     

# Foo Secondary lib:

# Clear vars
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# Include OpenCV
include 3rdparty/OpenCV-2.4.3-rc-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
# Target Build
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm   
# Library Name          
LOCAL_MODULE := FooMain     
# Set All SRC_FILES Together            
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/FooMain/src/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)     
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(SRC_FILES)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libFooSecondary
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/armeabi 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz -lm -ldl -lGLESv2 -lEGL -llog -lFooSecondary
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O2 -mno-thumb -Wno-write-strings
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O2 -mno-thumb -Wno-write-strings
# Compile as Shared Library     
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my Application.mk is:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

But, when I compile Android.mk using ndk-build I get the next Error:

```
Compile arm    : libFooSecondary <= *.c
SharedLibrary  : libFooSecondary.so
Install        : libFooSecondary.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libFooSecondary.so
SharedLibrary  : libFooMain.so

/home/user/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lFooSecondary

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libFooMain.so] Error 1
```

Why libFooSecondary.so is not found if is correctly compiled and installed?

Additionaly, if LOCAL_MODULE name change, for example, first one is LOCAL_MODULE := zname and second one is LOCAL_MODULE := aname, compile first the second one, i don't know why.

Comment: ndk-build works in the following order: first, it compiles all files that belong to the last project. Then it _"understands"_ that it needs another project, on which the last project depends (e.g. via `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`), and starts building it. If it does not have other dependencies, NDK can link the second library, and after that - the first. Bit if there are more dependencies, the same "algorithm" will be applied to all dependencies, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Android.mk` looks weird. Does it assign `LOCAL_PATH` somewhere? There is no need to assign `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` to duplicate `LOCAL_CFLAGS`, because ndk-build puts both sets of flags on C++ command line.

To understand better how NDK interprets your **Application.mk** and **Android.mk**, you can run

```
ndk-build V=1
```

This will echo all executed commands, including compilation and link, with all their parameters that NDK build assigns.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir) in header. It's the first thing I do. ndk-build V=1 could help me to solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: I have solved the problem putting a different File.mk for each library, and include it on top. But LOCAL_MODULE need prefix 1,2,3 to compile correctly, if not, start compiling the Main, and file to link the Secondary, don't compile it!

Comment: I cannot follow your explanation. But whatever works for you, that's good. After all, these makefiles are not the goal, but only a means to get your program working on a device.

Comment: hi, can you please explain to me how did you solve the problem? did you put a seperated mk file for the two librairies? i have the same problem and still can't resolve it

Comment: @GhadaSalem: is it the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418517/how-to-use-static-opencv-library that you are talking about?

Comment: @AlexCohn I tried to put the library as static to use it later but I still can't use this library(opencv) in my file.I'm talking about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362637/use-two-library-in-the-same-jni-file

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling FooSecondary as a static library and include it in FooMain as:
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libFooSecondary

The ndk doesn't play nicely with multiple shared libraries unless they're being dlopen'd.

Comment: I compile FooSecondary as using include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) , so, LOCAL_X_LIBRARIES must be SHARED

Comment: @AnthonyS: No, it's not hard to work with multiple shared libraries. Simply `System.load()` all of them in the dependency order (i.e. in this case, "FooSecondary" first, "FooMain" second.

Comment: @AlexCohn:  You're correct.  I forgot about the loading-libraries-from-JNI thing.   Piperoman:  I was suggesting that you try compiling it as a static library instead, but it's understandable if you want to keep it as a shared library.