# use two library in the same JNI file

Tags: android, c++, opencv, makefile, java-native-interface

I'm using **vuforia** API to make an augmented reality application.Now I'm trying to integrate another library (**opencv**). I made changes in the **android.mk** file. But i still can't use opencv library and QCAR library in the same file .cpp
I tried to access the java class to link between file which use QCAR and files which use OPENCV but this mapping is a time comsuming.
I need to use the two library in the same file. this is my android.mk file:

I edit the code as it was mentioned in the comments:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := QCAR-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = ../../../build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../build/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE := ImageTargets
USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1 := false
ifeq ($(USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1), true)
OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv1_CM
OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_1_1
else
OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv2
OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_2_0
endif

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-write-strings -Wno-psabi $(OPENGLES_DEF)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += \
-llog $(OPENGLES_LIB)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += QCAR-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ImageTargets.cpp SampleUtils.cpp Texture.cpp SampleMath.cpp 
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

mon fichier application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a 
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
```

when i build the project without adding any opencv function in my ImageTargets.cpp i get this:

```
E:\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= ImageTargets.cpp 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= SampleUtils.cpp 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= Texture.cpp 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= SampleMath.cpp 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_contrib.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android- sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_legacy.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_ml.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_stitching.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_objdetect.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_ts.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_videostab.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_calib3d.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_photo.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_video.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_features2d.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_highgui.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_androidcamera.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_flann.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_imgproc.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libopencv_core.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : liblibjpeg.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : liblibpng.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : liblibtiff.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : liblibjasper.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi/ 
 Prebuilt : libIlmImf.a <= jni/../../../OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi/ 
SharedLibrary : libImageTargets.so 
Install : libImageTargets.so => libs/armeabi/libImageTargets.so 
Install : libQCAR.so => libs/armeabi/libQCAR.so 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= ImageTargets.cpp 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= SampleUtils.cpp 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= Texture.cpp 
"Compile++ arm : ImageTargets <= SampleMath.cpp 
SharedLibrary : libImageTargets.so 
Install : libImageTargets.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libImageTargets.so 
Install : libQCAR.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libQCAR.so
```

But when i add an `opencv` function in the ImageTargets.cpp(which already use `QCAR library`) i get :`E:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/..‌​/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe‌​: Warning: ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_core.a(array.cpp.o): Unknown EABI object attribute 44`
Any ideas what am I doing wrong in this file?

Comment: You did not post the build output for your project, so it's kinda hard to tell what is wrong with your Android.mk

Comment: I added the build output to my question.thx

Comment: First of all, use `ndk-build V=1` to disclose the actual link command (it's enough to delete `obj/local/armeabi/libImageRargets.so` and build). Also, I only see the opencv prebuilt libraries copied once, for __armeabi__; if the _undefined reference_ error happens only for __armeabi-v7a__, that would mean that OpenCV has a problem with that ABI. Do you find the libraries in `OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a`? Maybe, you can simply drop __armeabi-v7a__ from your __Application.mk__?

Comment: Yes I have the prebuilt opencv librairies in both armeabi and armeabi-v7a. I use `ndk-build V=1` and now I get this error :`SharedLibrary  : libImageTargets.so   E:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: Warning: ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_core.a(array.cpp.o): Unknown EABI object attribute 44`

Comment: Something is still missing here... `V=1` should show the full command line of `ld.exe`. Anyway, a warning may just be a warning.. If I remember correctly, there was an unresolved reference __error__ before.

Comment: it was `unresolved reference` error but I remembered that I had changed the android.mk file so when I met it as in this question I don't have it any more.But I have the same warning that I have mentioned in my comment and in the question and I don't think that it is just a warning because i don't have now the `ImageTargets.so`.Is it related to the ndk version? I'm using `ndk-r8`.

Comment: This _could be_ incompatible NDK. Please consult OpenCV instructions. Also, the latest version is called r8e. Which flavour of r8 have you installed?

Comment: I moved now to ndk r8e. after reconfigure the project whith the new ndk, I don't have the opencv prebuilt librairies in both **armeabi** and **armeabi-v7a**. I have this warming:`C:/Development/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: hidden symbol '__aeabi_atexit' in C:/Development/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a(atexit_arm.o) is referenced by DSO ./obj/local/armeabi/libQCAR.so`.

Comment: Right. r8e uses the prebuilt libraries wigthout copying them to obj/local. But the new error shows that your version of OpenCV is not compatible with 8e.

Comment: I'm using opencv2.4.5 which support the ndk r8e as it is mentioned here:(http://opencv.org/opencv-2-4-5-is-out.html).

Comment: Sorry, the warning you showed (about `__aeabi_atexit`) is not caused by OpenCV, but by your QCAR library. You probably should rebuild this library with NDK r8e, and also make sure it uses parameters compliant with your __Application.mk__

Comment: what do you mean by `parameters compliant`???

Comment: STL, PLATFORM, CPPFLAGS