# how to use static opencv library

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to integrate `OpenCV` into my android project (using ndk).
When I made :`OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=static` I can't built the project I had this error:

```
E:\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd all 
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'opencv_contrib' in jni/Android.mk.    
E:/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by jni/Android.mk.
```

Any idea how can I solve it? I'm using `android-ndk-r8` and `OpenCV2.4.3`

Comment: Is `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := static` the first thing you do after `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`? Can you show us your Android.mk?

Answer (score 0):

I try to build two OpenCV-based native libs using single `Android.mk`. This [known issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2202) had been fixed at `OpenCV 2.4.4` release. I need to update OpenCV4Android SDK or add `OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off` line before the second inclusion of `opencv.mk`, if I want to use this version.